# No image after disconnecting HDMI

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-8-preview

I had connected my laptop to an external display via an HDMI cable in the developers preview of Windows 8.

After sometime I sent the laptop to hibernate mode, without disconnecting the HDMI cable. The next time I switched my laptop on, the screen was not working. I have tried to clone the display as well as extend it without any avail.

My only mode of viewing my laptop is via the HDMI external display again. Restarting the laptop also proves useless as the BIOS screen is also not displayed while booting up.

Answer (score 1):

Chaining the display settings within your operating system should not affect the viewing of your BIOS screen as this is displayed before any operating system is actually loaded on to your laptop. Which makes this very strange...

I would suggest trying to find the motherboard cell battery and removing this for a few min (if you can get to it) that should return all the BIOS settings to their default values and hopefully restore your screen to normal.

Answer (score 0):

What laptop is it? and is there a function or 'FN' button along with a laptop/monitor screen button that you can press?

[image: This old gem.]